# Top align text in multicolum page in document

Tags: multicol, alignment

I'm trying to have a page with my abstract (document) where one column on the left is my abstract in English, and the one on the right is my abstract in French. I need the columns to be separate. Because the French text is much longer than the English one, I reduced the size of the font, but now my left column with the English text is not aligned at the top. Is there a way to ensure that the alignment of the text in the `multicol` setting is aligned at the top?

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{multicol}

\small
\begin{multicols}{2}
\section*{Abstract}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

\columnbreak
\section*{Résumé}
machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin 

\end{multicols}
\normal

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend the `paracol` package for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\section*{Abstract}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

\switchcolumn
\small
\section*{Résumé}
machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin machin 

\end{paracol}

\end{document}

\end{document}
```

[image]